# How to use only Nullmailer to send emails with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, email

I have a Ubuntu server with [nullmailer](https://wiki.debian.org/nullmailer) installed on it to relay send emails to an actual SMTP server. Everything is working as intended when I execute the following command at the CLI.

```
echo "Test message" | mail -r "test@example.com" -s "This is just a test with nullmailer" "fakemail@example.com"
```

My question is: How can I use the `mail` with Symfony Mailer? I only see adapter for SendGrid and other providers. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nullmailer is such a simple daemon it doesn't provide a local smtp server so you'll have to use the [sendmail transport](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#transport).

The `MAILER_DSN` should be something like `sendmail://localhost` or `sendmail://your-host-name`.